# Why use separate Dart files for UI components in Flutter instead of keeping everything in a single file?

Tags: flutter, dart

My program contains two `.dart` files.

`main.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './question.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;

  void _answerQuestions() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'What\'s your favorite animal?',
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(questions[questionIndex]),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 1'),
              onPressed: _answerQuestions,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Answer 2'),
                onPressed: () => print('Answer 2 chosen')),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 3'),
              onPressed: _answerQuestions,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`question.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;

  Question(this.questionText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      questionText,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
    );
  }
}
```

Is the `Question` Class in `questions.dart` executed by pressing `Button` 1 or 3 (Answer 1, Answer 3)?

If I understand that correctly, the buttons will execute `onPressed: _answerQuestions,`, but `_answerQuestions` only changes the State of `questionIndex`, and is not calling something else, right? The UI gets rebuilt and the `Question` `Text` changes.

But `Question` Class does change the appearance of the text with the "style", this is its only task right now.

So why do we have a second dart file for that? We could simply change the style within `main.dart`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the the Question Class in questions.dart executed by pressing
> Button 1 or 3 (Answer 1, Answer 3)?

Both. `Question` is a `StatlessWidget` holding your question.

When you press any of the buttons (1 & 2) `MyAppState` gets rebuilt with a new question **index** and because you pass the question text to the Question Widget using that **index**, `Question(questions[questionIndex])`, `Question` will get a new value and show it, because you called `setState`, if you had not, behind the scenes it would still change the value but because the widget wouldn't be rebuilt, the visual side would stay the same.

The why you have two separate files? It makes it easier to see what your app is doing, especially for bigger projects. Usually, one file should have one purpose, do not mix functionalities in one file, or you'll get a messy code really fast.

In this case, the equivalent for not having the question in a separate file would be:

```
body: Column(
    children: [
        // from 
        // Question(questions[questionIndex]),
        // to
        Text(
            questions[questionIndex],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Answer 1'),
            onPressed: _answerQuestions,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Answer 2'),
            onPressed: () => print('Answer 2 chosen')),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Answer 3'),
            onPressed: _answerQuestions,
        ),
    ],
),
```

But what if you need to use that same question in several places?

```
Text(
    questions[questionIndex],
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
),
Text(
    questions[questionIndex],
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
),
Text(
    questions[questionIndex],
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
),
Text(
    questions[questionIndex],
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
),
```

You'll have to write that same code every time you need it, and this is a really simple one, imagine you have a widget with much more code, do you really want to write it all over again every time you need it?

No, you just create a new widget that has the functionality you need and call it whenever you need it.

```
Question(questions[questionIndex]),
Question(questions[questionIndex]),
Question(questions[questionIndex]),
Question(questions[questionIndex]),
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually tend to start a file for every new "screen" in the app. Also, I create one file for I/O (api connections, DB...), and a file for common functions.

It is good to have several files because the moment you want to build a big app, you will realise how long it is. My last app was around 10k lines of code. Impossible to maintain with only 1 file.

Also, dividing by file is useful for code reutilisation.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;

  void _answerQuestions() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'What\'s your favorite animal?',
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
          Text(
            questions[questionIndex],
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        ),

            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 1'),
              onPressed: _answerQuestions,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Answer 2'),
                onPressed: () => print('Answer 2 chosen')),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 3'),
              onPressed: _answerQuestions,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It can be done.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65041254/17726418) says:

> you'll get a messy code really fast.

You should follow best practices while learning a language. It is equally important, and will help you in the long run.